# In GSON, how to work with JSON attributes containing space?

Tags: android, json, gson, pojo

Since GSON sets the object(pojo)'s fields using reflection, what if the json attributes contain spaces?
Could we solve it without telling the server?

Example :

```
"node": {
            "Description": "Traffic Accident",
            "Date of Event": "02 September 2015",
            "Location": "Naypyitaw›Tatkon",
            "Type": "blah blah",
        }
```

You can't name the field as "Date of Event" in java pojo.

Comment: can you not use @serialize and then give your own name?

Comment: key name should not be `Date of Event` yes you should tell server guy.

Comment: it is not a valid JSON. You can't work with it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can parse JSON keys with whitespace with Gson by using `SerializedName` annotation.

Example:

```
@SerializedName("Date of Event") public String dateOfEvent;
```

Comment: thz Jared, that's what i need.

Comment: @CristyYG, I noticed on many of your other questions you haven't accepted an answer. Click the checkmark (not just the up arrow). It still isn't accepted as an answer. I would go back to your old questions and mark answers as accepted so they don't sit in "unanswered" land for eternity. :)

Comment: Right, I didn't check some of my questions  til so far which are not suitable answer for me.